# How can I list the number of packages in a remote channel?

Tags: conda, miniconda

I would like to be able to list the number of packages in channel. For now I've use conda search + awk.

Is there a better way to do this?

Why do I need this? I could use Conda client to obtain more information about a channel and use it for user information.

Regards!

Comment: You should be able to use the API, which will return a JSON structure and you can parse the `basename` field in those results to find the number of unique names. See https://api.anaconda.org/docs#/ for the available methods (you probably want 
`/channels/{owner_login}/{channel}` where `{owner_login}` is the channel name and `{channel}` is the label, which would be `main` for the main label in a channel). You'll need an API token as well, which you can get by signing up at anaconda.org

Comment: thanks for you answer!

Comment: Sure! If I had more time, I'd turn it into a real answer. Once you figure something out, come back and put it as an answer below :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's no possible using Conda client directly, but it's possible using the API.

According @darthbith:

> You should be able to use the API, which will return a JSON structure and you can parse the basename field in those results to find the number of unique names. See api.anaconda.org/docs# for the available methods (you probably want /channels/{owner_login}/{channel} where {owner_login} is the channel name and {channel} is the label, which would be main for the main label in a channel). You'll need an API token as well, which you can get by signing up at anaconda.org